# How can I implement RSS 2 in Code Igniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, rss2

How can I implement RSS 2 in Code Igniter?

Comment: These are helpful as well:

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/45813/P15/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS

http://validator.w3.org/feed/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these links:

> http://www.derekallard.com/blog/post/building-an-rss-feed-in-code-igniter/
>
> http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/45813/P15/
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS
>
> http://validator.w3.org/feed/